# Receiving a token from a clicked email

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm working on a web application with some team members and I have been tasked with the Password recovery. We are using mysql and node.js for the back-end and API layer. With the following npm packages: nodemailer, mysql, express, body-parser and bcrypt.

The issue at hand is I don't actually know how to create a link with a bcrypt token and then recive the token and interpret it and then send it to the html page/form with the user data.

I haven't tested the code as of yet but some input would be great:

```js
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  //Change DB name to the one you make.
  database: 'projectracetrack'
});

//User clicks on link in email. 
app.get('/recover/:token', function(req, res) {
  //here
});

app.post('/forget', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
  db.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db.query(sql, [req.body.email.toString()], function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      //Comparing email to database 
      if (result.email.toLowerCase() !== req.email.toLowerCase()) {
        //send reply that email 
        return res.send("Your email does not exist in the database, please use the registration page.");
      } else {
        var token;
        //encripting the token
        bcrypt.hash(result.username, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
          if (err) throw err;
          token = hash;
          sql = "INSERT INTO racers (RecoveryToken, RecoverTimeOut) WHERE email = " + result.email + " VALUES ? LIMIT 1";
          //inserting the token and data to the database                                                         HERE!!
          // 1 hour
          var data = [
            [token,
              Date.now() + 3600000 // 1 hour 
            ]
          ];
          db.query(sql, [data], function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
          });

          var mailOptions = {
            from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
            to: result.email,
            subject: 'Project Racetrack Password Recovery',
            text: 'Dear ' + result.username + '\n\n\
                                This is a confermation that you would like to recover your password please click on the link:' +
              'http://' + req.headers.host + '/recover/' + token + '\n\n\
                                If this has not been requested by you please contact our customer suppport\n\n\
                                Kind Regards\n\
                                Team'
          };

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            } else {
              console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You want us to eyeball-debug your code?

Comment: Sorry no mainly the interpreting the link when the user clicks it in the email attachment. i.e. `app.get('/recover/:token', function`

Comment: You can get token in `req.params.token`  in `app.get('/recover/:token'` and then validate from your table where you have inserted

Comment: Thanks one of my superior apprentices explained the token and the get request Now I can compare it with the database and time stamps: `app.get('/recover', function (req, res) { 
    console.log(req.param('token'));
    const utoken = req.param('token');
});`

Comment: And the link is created like this now: `'http://' + req.headers.host + '/recover/?token=' + token + '`